# Mantis Bug Tracker with Apache Tomcat Server

Tags: tomcat, mantis

I want to install mantis bug tracking tool on ubuntu where Apache tomcat server is already install. But do not find any link for this type of installation. If possible please share link in which complete process to install mantis on ubuntu with apache server is described.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The installation process is described in the MantisBT administration guide, which can be found here:

https://mantisbt.org/docs/master/en-US/Admin_Guide/html-desktop/#admin.install